# How to store user input into a variable and use that information for another variable

Tags: php, laravel

So I have four user input in a form tag:

```
<form id="alexa-query" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="text" name="ds.alexa.mainUrl" style="width:350px; border-radius:3px;">
    <input type="text" name="ds.alexa.competitorUrl1" style="width:350px; border-radius:3px;">
    <input type="text" name="ds.alexa.competitorUrl2" style="width:350px; border-radius:3px;">
    <input type="text" name="ds.alexa.competitorUrl3" style="width:350px; border-radius:3px;">
</form>
```

I store the input into four php variables:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $mainUrl = $_POST["ds.alexa.mainUrl"];
   $competitorUrl1 = $_POST["ds.alexa.competitorUrl1"];
   $competitorUrl2 = $_POST["ds.alexa.competitorUrl2"];
   $competitorUrl3 = $_POST["ds.alexa.competitorUrl3"];
?>
```

This happens in a blade at this location in the project:

```
\resources\views\users\admin\dynamic-dashboard\widget-steps\widget\general
```

In a different blade withing the project I need to use the information from those four variables into a single one:

```
$site = $mainUrl.$competitorUrl1.$competitorUrl2.$competitorUrl3;
```

The location of this blade is:

```
\app\Libraries\Services
```

I am new to laravel and to back-end programming so if my question seems stupid or I have done something wrong I am sorry. The idea is that I need the user input from those four input tags to be stored in the php variable called `$site`. So I don't need to store the input into a database I need to share it between two views.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: also - you shouldn't need to apologise for being new at something! in an ideal world, these kind of communities are there for exactly that reason - people to ask questions that they don't know / can't find the answer for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flash data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#flash-data):

> Sometimes you may wish to store items in the session only for the next
>   request. You may do so using the flash method. Data stored in the
>   session using this method will only be available during the subsequent
>   HTTP request, and then will be deleted.

and if you need to store variables in the session you can use

```
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');
```

and then you can retrieve the value using

```
$value = $request->session()->get('key', 'default');
```

Take a look at [session documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session).

Comment: How did you even understand his question? I am still trying to figure out his problem

Comment: I see that he wants to share information between 2 views, so this can be achieved using session variables.
I think he should avoid using the $_POST (Laravel has "Requests") and the processing should be done in a controller, not in the view.

Comment: Indeed this is what I am trying to do amieiro, sorry for not being so clear Huzaib....indeed I don't want to store the information in a database I just want to share it between two views

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid storing it in database, did you consider sessions? On your page where you save your submitted data into variables, save it also into session variables. like:

```
$_SESSION['competitorUrl1'] = $competitorUrl1 = $_POST["ds.alexa.competitorUrl1"];
```

Then you can access this data on other page with:

```
$_SESSION['competitorUrl1']
```

Of course that will be available only until the browser window is closed, in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two pieces of general programming advice that were given to me a long while ago, that i think are relevant here. (I've give a bit more of a direct answer below that too)

#### Separation of Concerns

Ideally, views should have very little logic in them - if any. And all that logic should be directly view related - not data related. Avoid making new variables, or editing existing ones in views.

Separating anything to do with manipulating data and rendering it (ie. your concerns) makes the code much easier to reason and think about.

#### Avoid Globals

Also, avoid the direct usage of globals and superglobals - like PHP's `$_POST` or `$_SESSION`.

Laravel actually has wrappers for all of them, that are almost always more friendly and safer to use. It's generally recommended to use them.

For example, you can get user input from the request object:

```
// You can use the facade anywhere in laravel
\Request::input('ds.alexa.competitorUrl1')
// or if you have the request object (like, in a controller)
$request->input('ds.alexa.competitorUrl1')
```

Again, not relying on a specific global state makes the code considerably easier to reason about and debug!

#### Actually answering your question

If you're doing what i think, then you're trying to pass data "sideways" between views, and have recognised that it is awkward :)

If so, there is likely a structural or architectural solution to your problem.

I think what you are trying to do is best done *above* the view level (in a `Controller` or, if there is a lot of logic to be done, in another class that the controller uses), and passed to the main view, which can pass it to any subviews.

The request object, for example, is available at the controller level (you can inject it - [see the example for method injection in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers)).

From there, you can get user input out of it, manipulate it however you like, and pass it to a view.

Comment: Very interesting advice, thank you very much, but can you please give me a bit of a more precise example? I mean, something specific for my case. So in the first view I should take the input like this? \Request::input('ds.alexa.competitorUrl1') And should I create a class in the controller that makes the same request there and echo it? Sorry I am still learning and right now I  am a proper noob.